# VBA code to create a new row based on cell data

Tags: vba, excel

What I am trying to achieve is to have Excel search each cell in row E for "GR". If it find GR, a new row will be created under it, the data from the previous row will be copied into the new row and the cell where the data was found will be changed to G and the new row's cell changed to R.

For example:

Current Dataset

```
 Friday B Fr GR
 Friday B Fr R
 Friday B Fr GR
 Friday B Fr G
 Friday B Fr G
```

After code is Run

```
 Friday B Fr G
 Friday B Fr R
 Friday B Fr R
 Friday B Fr G
 Friday B Fr R
 Friday B Fr G
 Friday B Fr G
```

Basically just creating a new row, copying that rows data and splitting up the GR.

```
Sub Method2()
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim strSearch As String
    strSearch = "GR"
    Set rng1 = Range("E:E").Find(strSearch, , xlValues, xlWhole)

For Each Cell In rng1
        With strSearch = True
        Active.Cell Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    'At this point I can't figure out how to put in the letters

        End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Please share the code you've already tried.

Comment: I don't see a question in this post

Comment: Question is how to write code to perform the action.

Comment: Press [alt]+F11 to open the VBE and immediately add a Module code sheet with [alt]+I, M. After that, it is just a matter of typing. After typing, tap [alt]+Q to return to your worksheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some code that should do the job for you

```
Sub SplitColE()
Dim cel As Range
For Each cel In Range("E:E") 'You can change the range to suit your data range
    If cel.Value = "GR" Then
        Rows(cel.Offset(1, 0).Row).Insert
        Rows(cel.Row).Copy Destination:=Rows(cel.Offset(1, 0).Row)
        cel.Value = "G"
        cel.Offset(1, 0) = "R"
    End If
Next
End Sub
```